# error en dart y flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

problema en la clase MyApp. despues me recomienda ponerla abstracta. al ponerla abstracta me da un error en runApp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

No es abstract, solo cambia el nombre del método dentro de esa clase , tienes un error ahí.

No es `buid` es `build`, debería quedar así :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
```